# "Have you called init_node()?"

Tags: ros, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everyone, when I'm trying to do the tutorial in http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29 , I have a problem when I try to execute

> rosrun beginner_tutorials talker.py

The error message is :

```
luigi@luigi-pc:~/ros_workspace/beginner_tutorials$ rosrun beginner_tutorials talker.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/luigi/ros_workspace/beginner_tutorials/nodes/talker.py", line 11, in <module>
    str = "hello world %s"%rospy.get_time()
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/src/rospy/rostime.py", line 222, in get_time
    return Time.now().to_sec()
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/src/rospy/rostime.py", line 150, in now
    raise rospy.exceptions.ROSInitException("time is not initialized. Have you called init_node()?")
rospy.exceptions.ROSInitException: time is not initialized. Have you called init_node()?
```

Anyone Can help me??

Thank you in advance

Luigi

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31702/%22have-you-called-init_node()?%22/) by [palmlster](https://answers.ros.org/users/2172/palmlster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2012-04-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-04-12**:
Can you please post your python code? It at least differs somehow since the error comes in line 11 and not in line 9 which should be the str = ... line when you directly copy-pasted the code from the tutorial.

**Comment by [palmlster](https://answers.ros.org/users/2172/palmlster/) on 2012-04-13**:
yes Lorenz, here it is :

**Comment by [palmlster](https://answers.ros.org/users/2172/palmlster/) on 2012-04-13**:
https://sites.google.com/site/palmlster/home/code

**Comment by [palmlster](https://answers.ros.org/users/2172/palmlster/) on 2012-04-13**:
in that page you can find the used code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to indent the `while` loop so that it becomes part of the function `talker`. Right now, the `while` loop is getting executed, and `talker` is never called.

---

Originally posted by [Cody](https://answers.ros.org/users/1588/cody/) with karma: 125 on 2012-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0